# Powershell - Show only down IP addresses

Tags: powershell

Need some help adjusting this code so that it will only provide IP addresses that are not pinging and will be exported to a CSV.  Currently, it outputs both up and down IP's and I want to clean up some of the clutter.

```
$ping = (Test-Connection -ComputerName $comp.IPAddress -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
if($ping)
{
    $status = "Up"
}
else
{
    $status = "Down"
}

[pscustomobject]@{
    Location = $comp.Location
    IP = $comp.IPAddress
    Status = $status
}
```

I have tried manipulating the $status variable but haven't had any luck.  I am sure it's something very simple, I am just missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# -Quiet means we just return a boolean true / false value
$ping = Test-Connection -ComputerName ($comp.IPAddress) -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Quiet
if(-not $ping) 
{
    # we only care about when it's down, so move the logic to return our object here
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Location = $comp.Location
        IP = $comp.IPAddress
        Status = 'Down'
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aramus, Welcome to SO!

Test-Connection returns a Null if the connection is down so...

```
    $ping = (Test-Connection -ComputerName $($comp.IPAddress) -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    if($Null -ne $ping)
    {
        $status = "Up"
    }
    else
    {
        $status = "Down"
    }
```

Also note the $() around $Comp.IPAddress, this is to insure the parser fetches the IPAddress before running the rest of the command.